# Prime Number List Program

Tags: loops, assembly, hardware, primes

first of all i want to prove that this is not a homework http://computer.atlas4e.com/

i really need to understand this with an explanation, because I'm trying to understand the basic of the computer by my self thanks for the help

```
`Prime Number List Program 
Write a main program that generates a list of prime numbers. The program should use the PrimeTest subroutine to test whether each of the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6…, 255 & 256 is a prime. Each number that is found to be a prime should be added to a list in memory. The list of primes should be stored in consecutive memory locations.  Use a location named StartPrimeList to point to the start address of the prime number list. Use a pointer called PrimeListPtr to point to the (current) end of the list, PrimeListPtr will be incremented every time a prime number is appended to the list.
Use a location named PrN to store the number that you are checking. Start by storing a 2 in PrN. In a loop, you should call PrimeTest to determine whether PrN is a prime. If PrN is a prime, then append it to the list. Then add 1 to PrN and jump back to the start of the loop to test the next value of PrN.`
The output of the program should appear starting at location StartPrimeList as follows:-
Address Contents
 [StartPrimeList]   2
[StartPrimeList+1]  3
[StartPrimeList+2]  5
[StartPrimeList+3]  7
    …
    …
[StartPrimeList+?]  Largest Prime <= 256

(251 - 54th prime number starting from 2 <=256)
(257 - 55th prime number >256)

`

Mark Allocations for Program 2

•   A program header in the program listing explaining how the program works.   
•   Sensible/Relevant program comments on sections of assembler language.       
•   Relevant labelling of loops and data items.                         [4]
•   Program runs successfully on xComputer and produces correct output for given input. 
`
```

Comment: One other resource you might be interested in: [Programming from the Ground Up](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/), Jonathan Barlett

Comment: @robert The question is implicit: "How do I find someone doing my assignment for me?". Nowadays they  don't even bother to reformulate the assignment into a question, to much work probably.

Answer (score 0):

"Write a main program that generates a list of prime numbers."  This is your basic question.  further details are given later to help you answer it.

"The program should use the PrimeTest subroutine to test whether each of the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6…, 255 & 256 is a prime."  Can you do this part?  If not, then write the best code you can to do it and ask here again with a specific question.

"Each number that is found to be a prime should be added to a list in memory." Can you do this part?  If not, then write the best code you can to do it and ask here again with a specific question.

"The list of primes should be stored in consecutive memory locations."  Can you do this part?  If not, then write the best code you can to do it and ask here again with a specific question.

"Use a location named StartPrimeList to point to the start address of the prime number list." You should have got the message by now.  Use the excellent advice given in the question itself to help you.  Write your code.  If it works, then fine.  If it doesn't then post it here, explaining what it should do and what you think the problem might be.  Tell us what you have tried, and what didn't fix the problem.  That will help us having to repeat your work.

We won't write your program for you.  You have to write it; we will *help* you write it.